# Count of Open\Current Records by half year

Tags: date, count, powerbi, measure, selected

I have a calendar table and two other tables, of records A and records B. The calendar date has an active relationship with records A table and an inactive relationship with records B table. Relation type one to many as below.

[image: Data Model]

What I'd like to calculate for the records B table is a measure to display a count of the number of open\current records when I select a half year from the slicer. It should calculate the open records from the previous half years and the current ones.

The slicer's field is Half Year text format (which is the Half Year when the records were created), but the relationships with the calendar table is based on creation records date - a date data type). More important, I have only one date column in the Records B table, which is the creation date to calculate the measure and no end/close date. That is why I find tricky to calculate the measure.

I've tried the following solutions:

I've followed this link:

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Community-Blog/HR-Analytics-Active-Employee-Hire-and-Termination-trend/bc-p/2957695

In particular, modifying this formula:

```
Current Employees = CALCULATE(COUNTx(FILTER(Employee,Employee[Start Date]<=max('Date'[Date]) && (ISBLANK(Employee[End Date]) || Employee[End Date]>max('Date'[Date]))),(Employee[Employee Id ])),CROSSFILTER(Employee[Start Date],'Date'[Date],None))
```

Instead of `crossfilter` I used `USERELATIONSHIP` as it has an inactive relationship with the calendar date and removed the code that mentioned `employee[End Date]`.

I have also used the `count('Records B', Filter('Records B'[Creation Date] <=SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Date]))`

But the `<` sign in both measures it looks like is ignored.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend you to go through that solution link again to fully understand how it works. I do not understand your setup/model, but to give you some hints as starting point to understand that linked solution: **1.** the reason why there is an inactive link is because there are 2 relationships from the date table to different columns (start and end) in the same table. **USERELATIONSHIP** help to switch between them. (e.g. if you have the date table connected to 2 different tables as 1:n, both connection can be “whatever” in the sense that they are not in potential conflict to each other)

Comment: **2.** in some of the measures there, they use **CROSSFILTER** with the parameter “none” in order to turn off that active relationship. This is because as per definition USERELATIONSHIP switches between the active and inactive, i.e.  there is still one active. In those cases, they wanted to turn off both links to the date table.  Good luck!

Comment: **ad to 1.** both table at the n-side of the relation to the date table do not have any relation to each other in the model as long as both relations are unidirectional (and of course unless defined otherwise in a measure or calculated column calculation). **ad to 2.** technically CROSSFILTER just act on the connection given as parameter. It does not turn off all/both connections. In that case it turns off the active one, and as a result both are off (aka one inactive)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Being a data model based on fake data, I missed to add the relationship between Records A table and Records B table, which with the real data exists. Sorry for that.
Based on the solution link I provided, the Records A table is the Employees table of the solution, Records B table is a another type of records which I need to calculate the same measure as was done for the Employees table of the solution (in my case it's the Records A table).

Comment: I see. I still suggest you to check whether you can “replace” CROSSFILTER with USERELATIONSHIP in your measure. Cheers!

Comment: I've already done that as mentioned in my post, but the results are not exact.

Comment: Sorry, it came across wrong. I meant to write, you should check whether you can **really** “replace” them …  As I mentioned, they do not do the same thing. That measure can work w/o CROSSFILTER if both of the links are inactive in the model. But then USERELATIONSHIP is not needed either. One “requirement” for that measure to work is to deactivate any links to the date table. In your case, you need to check that the “disconnected” state between date table and table B is fulfilled for that measure while having also a link between table A and B, and table A and date table in your model.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I will give it a go and see what come sup. Thanks again.

Comment: I've followed your suggestion: created a link between Table A and B with Table A linked actively to Date table and removed any relationship between Date Table and Table B. The calculations are Blank, instead of showing a number. If I link Table B and Date table with an inactive relationship, I need to use USERALATIONSHIP in order to visualise the right count. So, I am back to the start. Any clue on how to write the measure for TAble B?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the calculations using this method applied to table B. Link: https://carldesouza.com/power-bi-dax-userelationship-multiple-dates/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).